# Is it correct to say "I am going to the workshop" or "I am going to the meeting" in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, phrase-usage

I want to send my children to school using British Education System to get GCSE and A-Level qualification.

I roughly know that GCSE maybe equals to k9 or k10 in the USA or other countries and A-Level maybe equals to k12. But I am not so sure.

Then a school organized an event explaining British Education System and other relevant information. In that event, an expert, who knows about it, will explain that to attendees and they might ask the expert some questions. The attendees might also share their opinions or thoughts relating to the topic.

Is that event called "**a workshop**" or "**a meeting**"?

For example, "**I am going to the workshop/meeting/....**"

Comment: Did you look up definitions for "workshop" and "meeting"? In this context, the former is more often used in respect of *interactive* "make and do" sessions. For example, one or more people with advanced skills in some activity "host" a workshop where they help learners to perform the activity (playing guitar, flower arranging, or whatever). Your meeting might barely even involve "discussion" (it could be little more than a ***talk, presentation*** with the possibility of questions from the audience at the end).

Comment: As to the "quality" of the qualifications, generally in the UK you'll leave school to start a degree at 18. But you won't normally be offered a place at university unless you've got at least 2 (usually 3, or even 4) reasonably good grade GCSE "A" levels (you usually need a good string of "O" Levels to be able to study for "A" Levels). And *approximately*, a university degree is the same level of qualification everywhere.

Comment: Fumble, you are nearly 35 years out of date if you talk about "O" levels! They do exist in some international contexts, but were replaced by GCSEs in the English and Welsh system.  Don't call it the UK system or the British system, or the Scots get miffed.  They don't have A levels, O levels or GCSEs, but Standard and Highers.

Answer (score 1):

Meeting, presentation, event, talk.... these are all possible words to use.  The right one will be the one the organiser uses.  So if the person who is organising the event calls it a "presentation" then that is what it is.

Generally a workshop will be an event in which peers meet to discuss a particular topic intensively.  So if several education experts are meeting to plan a curriculum, that might be a workshop.  But if one expert is meeting non-experts, that isn't a workshop.

Answer (score 0):

"Meeting" is a generic term for a group of people getting together. It can describe most types of gatherings, religious, business, social, or educational. It would be unusual to describe a group of people meeting socially as a "meeting", but more because we tend to think of meetings as having an object or a purpose. This is almost always going to be an unobjectional word choice unless the organizer is *specifically* calling the event something else, and even then, it will still be accurate.

"Workshop", in terms of a gathering of people, usually involves expertise, and a sharing of information. It's a learning experience. People are going with the expectation of increasing their skills by interacting with skilled peers, and there will be a lot of participation from people other than the organizer.

Another word you might consider in this case would be a *seminar*, which covers the idea of "meeting for educational purposes" without the sort of advanced ideas of participation that linger around "workshop." A seminar would differ from a workshop by being more "top down". It in a seminar setting, it is common for there to be a single expert and many learners, rather than many experts sharing experiences.

I would say, if there is any doubt, to default to the word "meeting". Both workshops and seminars are *kinds* of meetings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).